# KeyError: Timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, plotly

I am trying to construct an interactive coronavirus map that can change over time. I have data on cases by country and date. The data type for values in the 'Date' column are datetime64.

However, when I try to plot an interactive map, it seems that the date values are causing an error. How should I fix it?

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import plotly as py 
import datetime
import plotly.express as px 
import plotly.graph_objs as go 
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots 
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected = True)
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Public\Documents\covid_19_data.csv')
df = df.rename(columns = {'Country/Region' : 'Country'})
df = df.rename(columns = {'ObservationDate' : 'Date'})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.info()
df_datecountry = df.groupby(['Date', 'Country']).sum().reset_index().sort_values('Date', ascending = True)
fig = px.choropleth(df_datecountry, 
                    locations = 'Country', 
                    locationmode = 'country names',
                    color = 'Confirmed',
                    hover_name = 'Country', 
                    animation_frame = 'Date')
```

error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-69e836d40d17> in <module>
----> 1 fig = px.choropleth(df_datecountry, 
      2                     locations = 'Country',
      3                     locationmode = 'country names',
      4                     color = 'Confirmed',
      5                     hover_name = 'Country',

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_chart_types.py in choropleth(data_frame, lat, lon, locations, locationmode, geojson, featureidkey, color, facet_row, facet_col, facet_col_wrap, facet_row_spacing, facet_col_spacing, hover_name, hover_data, custom_data, animation_frame, animation_group, category_orders, labels, color_discrete_sequence, color_discrete_map, color_continuous_scale, range_color, color_continuous_midpoint, projection, scope, center, fitbounds, basemap_visible, title, template, width, height)
   1071     colored region mark on a map.
   1072     """
-> 1073     return make_figure(
   1074         args=locals(),
   1075         constructor=go.Choropleth,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py in make_figure(args, constructor, trace_patch, layout_patch)
   2021                 val = group_name[i]
   2022                 try:
-> 2023                     m.updater(trace, m.val_map[val])  # covers most cases
   2024                 except ValueError:
   2025                     # this catches some odd cases like marginals

KeyError: Timestamp('2020-01-22 00:00:00')
```

Ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- **animation_frame** needs to be a string
- have used OWID data to demonstrate,  **date** column is a string in data frame.  Have used date version of it for reducing data frame to most recent 30 days

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
# get OWID data
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
    requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv").text))

# used for filtering
dt = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
# last 30 days and exclude regional aggregations
fig = px.choropleth(df.loc[dt.ge(dt.max()-pd.Timedelta(days=30))].dropna(subset=["continent"]), 
                    locations = 'location', 
                    locationmode = 'country names',
                    color = 'new_deaths',
                    hover_name = 'location', 
                    animation_frame = 'date')

fig.update_layout(margin={"t":0,"b":0,"l":0,"r":0})
```